# Joining CSV with shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins

I am aware that this questions has been asked but I haven't really seen a satisfactory answer. I have loaded a CSV file into QGIS.

[image: Picture of CSV table]

It has been imported properly, with the first column as a string and the second as an integer.

However, when I join it to a shapefile - with a common field the name of the city/shire - the total field comes in with null values.

[image: Joined attribute table]

Comment: Please upload readable screenshots.

Comment: I had to strain my eyes to see it, but one field has a suffix ' city' or ' shire', the other doesn't. That's why your fields don't match up, that's why you get NULLs. It's almost always a bad idea to try to join on something like a name. Are there any other proper unique ids you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique ID field in the first column of the CSV file and populate it with a sequence (1,2,3...).  Then load the CSV and join it to the shapefile.

I've had Qgis display null values in the attribute table until I included an ID column to the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that and it didn't work. I know that the csv fields are correct as the numbers are showing "int" and the text "string".